# Propagation of errors including deviations

Tags: measurement-error

I have $n$ experiments, and for each experiment $i$ there were a variable number $m_i$ of measures $y_{ij}$ taken, which were combined resulting in a single measure $x_i = \frac{\sum_j y_{ij}}{m_i}$ with an associated error $\delta_i = \frac{\sigma_i}{\sqrt{m_i}}$, where $\sigma_i$ is the sample standard deviation of $y_{ij}$ for all $j$s in $i$.

The measures can be combined with the weighted average $x = \frac{\sum x_i w_i}{\sum w_i}$ and the errors with $\delta = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\sum w_i}}$, where $w_i = \frac{1}{\delta_i^2}$.

My question is, how can we include the errors between $x_i$s? If $x_i$s were given without errors, then we would calculate $\delta = \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$, where $\sigma$ is the sample standard deviation of the $x_i$s. With $\delta_i$s supplied, we're ignoring $\sigma$.